# Docker container monitor with splunk

Tags: docker, containers, splunk

I have a docker service for my application running on Google Cloud VM.
On the same VM, i have installed splunk to monitor the created container.

I had gone over some tutorials and was first testing to push container metrics via HTTP Event collector by a hello-world container.
I used the following command:

```
sudo docker run --log-driver=splunk \
       --log-opt splunk-url=http://34.121.xx.xxx:8088 \
       --log-opt splunk-token=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx \
       --log-opt splunk-insecureskipverify=true \
       hello-world
```

But it fails to create that container and gives the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: Options http://34.121.xx.xxx:8088/services/collector/event/1.0: read tcp 10.128.x.x:39404->34.121.xx.xxx:8088: read: connection reset by peer.ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

10.128.x.x is the Internal IP of the VM.

I am not sure why its happening like this. I am new to this. Can anyone help ? AM i missing some config ?

Answer (score 1):

You were incredibly close. The only thing I changed was *http* to *https* on the second line and it started

```
sudo docker run --log-driver=splunk \
      --log-opt splunk-url=https://localhost:8088 \
      --log-opt splunk-token=replace-with-your-token \
      --log-opt splunk-insecureskipverify=true \
      hello-world
```

Stdout logs from the docker container are visible in Splunk:

[image]